# Calculating the determinant of this complicated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I am calculating the characteristic polynomial for this matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\ 1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\ \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 2 &\cdots & n \end{pmatrix}$$
First I was asked to figure out that $0$ is an eigenvalue, and since it is not invertible then $0$ is an eigenvalue, and its' geometric multiplicity is $n-1$. Now I need to calculate the characteristic polynomial but I am finding this determinant hard!

$$\mbox{det}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda - 1 & -2 & \cdots & -n \\ -1 & \lambda - 2 & \cdots & -n \\ \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ -1 & -2 & \cdots & \lambda -n \end{pmatrix} = ? $$

Comment: Hint: You know $0$ is an eigenvalue o multiplicity $n-1.$ Calculating the trace should tell you the other eigenvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the trace of the matrix $A$ so
$$\lambda=1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
hence the chararcteristic polynomial is
$$\chi_A=x^{n-1}\left(x-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Why is the last eigenvalue the trace of the matrix?

Comment: @TheNotMe: you are aware that the trace is equal to the sum of all the eigenvalues, and you also know that $n-1$ of the eigenvalues are zero. Thus...

Comment: Is that always valid? I mean, $A$ is not a diagonal matrix, is your theorem still valid?

Comment: @TheNotMe To determine the Characteristic polynomial it suffices to know the eigenvalues of the matrix whatever it is diagonalizable or not diagonalizable

Comment: Well, if you don't mind me asking an extra question. Given that exact above matrix $A$. How do we figure out what the minimum ploynomial is? I mean surely I can't try $n-1$ options to figure out which option gives $m_A(A) = 0$. Any idea?

Comment: @TheNotMe Since this matrix is diagonalizable then the minimal polynomial is simply $m_A(x)=x\left(x-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: add to the first column all the others. We get $\lambda-\frac{n(n+1)}2$ for each entry. Then use linearity with respect to this column, and finally do $L_j\leftarrow L_j+jL_1$.