# Finding the characteristic polynomial of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I have a question about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408511/calculating-the-determinant-of-this-complicated-matrix).

How can we know that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is $n-1$?
I get that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ because $\textrm{det}A=0$, but I can't get why its geometric multiplicity is $n-1$.

Comment: The geometric multiplicity of $0$ is just the dimension of the null space of $A$ (sometimes called the "nullity" of $A$). Without computation, $A$ plainly has rank $1$ (for example because the dimension of its row space is clearly $1$, and the dimension of the row space is equal to the rank). By the rank-nullity theorem, its nullspace has dimension $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(1, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, ..., 0)$, $(1, 0, -\frac{1}{3}, 0, ..., 0)$, ..., $(1, 0,..., 0, -\frac{1}{n})$ are linearly independent engenvectors.

Another way of seeing it is by simply noting that all the rows are equal. (The thing written in the paragraph above illustrates why it is enough to note this).